# Save wifi auth preferences in ios

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I want to save authentication of my hotspot in my user preferences. Ex: I sign into my wifi using an app with my username and password, then unblock my network, so next time I'm go in this LAN, it should use the credentials I've put in app. So app has to save the wifi auth in user profile. I'm using `NSUserDefaults` to store my user and keychain for password. Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't a way for the app to directly setup an access point in the iOS system; I can not see a reason to save wifi authentication credentials in your app if the system will do this already (probably in a more secure manner)? If you simply save this in your user's preferences, then you will get into security issues if you want to change this password later.
However, yes you can distribute a provisioning profile which contains the credentials to your access point so that the user doesn't need to type it in. You could for example, from the app, open an URL pointing to a server web address that will serve the profile for your users. But then you don't even need an app just for that.. you could generate a QR code pointing to that URL and use one of the existing QRCode decoding apps for example.